Outside Installation of Window AC
Can I set a window unit completely OUTSIDE and vent ONLY the cold air into my sailboat via vent hose, similar to that used to vent hot air out from a portable AC located inside?  The fan would suck outside air across the evaporator coils and blow it into the boat. I know it may cause some positive pressure inside (which isn't airtight) and be less efficient, but would it work well enough?  I also foresee the thermostat setting being useless.  Any comments or advise would be greatly appreciated.

You have 120V power on your sailboat?

How would the AC deal with motion of boat and corrosive environment, or is this on the boat while docked only?

Is it technically possible? Sure. Is it commercially available? Gods only know; go shopping.

Note that you do want to draw inside air into the machine to cool it; that burns a heck of a lot less energy then taking the hot outside air and trying to cool it down. So, like the machines you mentioned, you would want to hoses and you would not get positive pressure.

Simple answer:  Yes it will blow cooler air inside your boat.  Whether that will satisfy your requirements  can be known only by you.  It will of course be terribly inefficient.  My advice would be, use the portable inside. Much more efficient.
